# InvalidCastException when selection changes in a WPF TreeView

Tags: wpf

To handle the `TreeView.SelectedItemChanged` event, I have an attached behavior that binds to a command.

Ordinarily, the `RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue` property contains a reference to one of my view-model objects, and I can then pass this on as the argument to `ICommand.CanExecute` and `ICommand.Execute`. I'm using `RelayCommand` from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), but I've got a `RelayCommand<T>` that casts to the expected type.

However, in certain scenarios, `RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue` contains a `TreeViewItem`, displayed as `{System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem Header:{DisconnectedItem} Items.Count:0}` in the debugger.

This causes my `RelayCommand<T>` to throw an `InvalidCastException`.

**Question: what is this mysterious `TreeViewItem` and where does it come from?**

I'm aware that I can avoid the exception by changing `RelayCommand<T>.Execute` from using `(T)value` to using `value as T`, but I'd like to know what the root cause is.

Answer (score 1):

A DisconnectedItem is a TreeViewItem that is no longer in your TreeView (i.e. that has been removed from the tree).

Comment: OK. Any idea why I'm seeing one in the SelectionChanged event handler?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting; do you do anything out of the ordinary with the treeview, as in control templating? Is it the actual built-in treeview or a class that inherits it? It could have something to do with virtualization but it definitely shouldn't happen ordinarily I think.

Comment: I have an `<ItemTemplate>` and an `<ItemContainerStyle>`, but I've not done anything (yet) with control templating.